# How to view the contents of folders inside the Recycle Bin on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I deleted some directories using the recycle bin and now I would like to review the contents before deleting them forever. I can only see the folder names, not their content. A right click on properties gives me the size and file count. I could not easily find a way to see what really was deleted.

Can I visualize the content of deleted folders in some way?

Comment: I don't think you can, you have to remove the folder to view the contents first

Answer (score 1):

You can't. As its not develop for view the content of the folder, you have to restore it back to the destination from where's you delete it.

Comment: I see... but the OS seems to be able to restore the files so the information about them is stored somewhere. Maybe this can be read and made visible with some other tool. It seems that you are right that the OS itself doesn't provide tools for this purpose but some 3rd party tools do maybe...

Comment: @jdehaan at the moment there is no third party software IIRC. But if there is I'll try to find it, it would be interesting for me too.